# Get Publications list which are (pages, content) enabled to be publishable

Tags: xml

is there a good way to get a list of publications which are publishable (pages, content).. i know we can get the list and then remove the nodes based on a criteria..

PublicationsFilterData filter = new PublicationsFilterData();
XElement publications = client.GetSystemWideListXml(filter);

Comment: not 100% sure I understand your requirement? In theory, anything in a publication is publishable as long as the publication is setup with the correct target information and mappings - except when a structure group is marked as "non-publishable", which IMO is rather rare. Can you expand a bit on what you're trying to achieve?

Comment: sorry for the confusion Nuno.. So we have pubs with 010,020,040,050,070.. 070 pubs are allowed to be publishable (configured in a target as allowed pubs).. i am trying to get the list of 070 pubs using core service.. any better way to do this?

Comment: OK - so you need a list of publications that are allowed to publish. I'm rusty here, but you could probably get them by looping through the Publication Targets and getting the list of publications in there? There's maybe an easier way, but I'm unaware of it.